# Ubuntu 16.04 Permission Denied

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

`index.php` is located at `/var/www/html/`

It tries to include `autoload.php` from `/root/vendor`

And I'm getting `include_once(../../../root/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied`

Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: You need to update permissions for the directory(s) in question.

Comment: I did it using sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www

Comment: Check where your autoload.php is, it's probably under /var/www/html... rather than /root/vendor

Comment: It is in /root/vendor/

Comment: I'm using composer if it matters

Comment: @vohosamedi doing `sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www` is probably not the best idea, it opens the door for lots of security risks later on and I'd probably only grant write access to a directory on a per directory basis so by default I'd use `755`. That will grant the owner of the script to read, write, execute. group/everyone would be able to read. I'd take a look at https://getcomposer.org/download/ and run that in the directory where you're trying to use it. That'd be the simplest approach.

Answer (score -1):

1. Enter your terminal and run this command in your terminal.

```
sudo nautilus
```

This command will enter you as root into the files application and mostly allow you to do anything to the files that you need to change.

2. go to the file that you want to change permissions on, mostly visit the folder var, then the folder www, then the folder html.
3. Once you are here, right click the index.php file and click properties, or permissions.
4. Change the permissions to read and write or create & delete for all of the options.

I hope I was able to help and much clearer this time, as I have received a downvote for not being clear enough.